# Functions with higher kinds?

Tags: haskell, types, data-kinds

Suppose the following data types are defined:

```
data X a = X {getX :: a}
data Y a = Y {getY :: a}
data Z a = Z {getZ :: a}
```

Must there be three separate functions, `getX`, `getY`, and `getZ`? It seems to me that there could be a function defined something like this:

```
get :: forall (τ :: (* -> *)) (a :: *). τ a -> a
get (_ x) = x
```

Obviously this is not valid standard Haskell, but there are so many extensions to GHC that seem like they might have a solution (`RankNTypes`,`ExistentialQuantification`,`DataKinds`,etc.). Besides the simple reason of avoiding a tiny amount of typing, there is the benefit of avoiding the namespace pollution that the record solution creates. I suppose this is really just a more implicit solution than using a type class like this:

```
class Get f where
  get :: f a -> a
```

However, it appears that defining a generic function would be more useful than a type class, because the fact that it is implicitly defined means it could be used in many more places, in the same way that `($)` or `(.)` is used. So my question has three parts: is there a way to accomplish this, is it a good idea, and if not, what is a better way?

Comment: What would your `get` function do if it was given a list (that is, if `τ` was `[]`)?

Comment: Well, it makes an implicit assumption that's not going to work. There's no reason to assume a type with a final type variable of kind * has a single constructor that takes a single argument of the type in question.

Answer (score 10):

How about this type?

```
newtype Pred a = Pred (a -> Bool)
```

Or this one?

```
data Proxy a = Proxy
```

There's no way to get an `a` out of a `Pred a`. You can only put `a`s in. Likewise, there's no way to get an `a` out of a `Proxy a`, because there aren't any `a`s inside it.

So a function `get :: forall f a. f a -> a` can't exist in general. You need to use a type class to distinguish between those types `f` from which you can extract an `a` and those from which you can't.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that unconstrained generic type of `get` certainly can't work. This would also allow you to extract, say, a [`Void`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Void.html) value from `Const () :: Const () Void`.

You can however obtain a suitably constrained version of this function quite simply with [generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html). You still need a type class, but not need to define instances in the traditional sense. It ultimately looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}
import GHC.Generics

class Get τ where
  get :: τ a -> a

data X a = X a deriving (Generic1, Get)
data Y a = Y a deriving (Generic1, Get)
data Z a = Z a deriving (Generic1, Get)
```

To actually get this to work, we only need two weird representation-type instances:

```
instance Get f => Get (M1 i t f) where get = get . unM1
instance Get Par1 where get = unPar1
```

Now the actual implementation for `X`, `Y` and `Z` can just use a default signature and reduce the extraction to the underlying type-representation. To this end, define the class thus:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class Get τ where
  get :: τ a -> a
  default get :: (Generic1 τ, Get (Rep1 τ)) => τ a -> a
  get = get . from1
```